# Font-awesome class fa is not being added with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, font-awesome, addclass

I have a button where I want the HTML and font-awesome icon to change on an odd number of clicks and revert back on an even number of clicks.

For example, I have a button named `mute`. If a user clicks on the button, I want the html to change to `unmute` and the font-awesome class to be replaced. If the user clicks on the button again I want the button to revert back to `mute` and so on.

This code should work and it does change the URL and the class. But it doesn't add the font-awesome initialization class `fa`.

When I inspect the element, I get this

```
<button id="mute" class="btn btn-primary fa-volume-off"> Mute</button>
```

With JQuery's `addClass` method you can add multiple classes by separating them with a space. Based on this, the element should be this

```
<button id="mute" class="btn btn-primary fa fa-volume-off"> Mute</button>
```

Here is my code

```
var clicks = 0;
    $("#mute").click(function() {
            clicks += 1;
            if (clicks % 2 === 1) {
                    $(this).html(" Un-mute");
                    $(this).addClass("fa fa-volume-up");
                    $(this).removeClass("fa fa-volume-off");
                    apiswf.rdio_setVolume(0);
            }
            else {
                $(this).html(" Mute");
                $(this).addClass("fa fa-volume-off");
                $(this).removeClass("fa fa-volume-up");
                apiswf.rdio_setVolume(100);
            }
    });
```

I do not understand why the `fa` class does not get added.

Comment: maybe not even add/remove the fa class at all?

Comment: Do you really need to count clicks? Wouldn't it be simpler to just call `toggleClass` on both classes on every click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the class and then add the class. Swap the position of the two methods in both muting or unmuting

Answer (score 5):

The problem is you removing fa class with removeClass method immediately after adding it . Change to this :

```
$(this).removeClass("fa-volume-off");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are `removeClass` with `fa` in it after `addClass`

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmaozgwf/)

```
var clicks = 0;
$("#mute").click(function() {
    clicks += 1;
    if (clicks % 2 === 1) {
        $(this).html(" Un-mute");
        $(this).removeClass("fa fa-volume-off");
        $(this).addClass("fa fa-volume-up");
        apiswf.rdio_setVolume(0);
    }
    else {
        $(this).html(" Mute");
        $(this).removeClass("fa fa-volume-up");
        $(this).addClass("fa fa-volume-off");
        apiswf.rdio_setVolume(100);
    }
});
```

Also, the `removeClass` both have `fa` even though you add `fa` every `addClass`... So should decide how you actually want to handle the `fa`.